# system.collection.generic.list system.string getting returned instead of actual data

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq expression that I am using to return a list of strings in a CSV file. Problem is that it returns `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]` where there should be data for each person.

This is the expression

```
  foreach (Person person in persons)
            {
                var finalValue = person.PersonDatas.Where(x => x.FinalValue != null).ToString();

                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\"",
                    person.ClientInternalPerson_ID,
                    person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName,
                    finalValue
                                           ));
            }
```

I also tried

```
var finalValue = person.PersonDatas.Where(x => x.FinalValue != null).ToString();
```

but all that returned was

`System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator'1[Project.Core.Models.PersonData]`

Comment: please post an [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `.ToString` on your query because it returns a record set(actually an `IEnumerable<PersonData>`), not a single value.  You will then need to iterate through them like this:

```
foreach (Person person in persons)
{
  var finalValues = person.PersonDatas.Where(x => x.FinalValue != null);
  foreach(var finalValue in finalValues)
  {
    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\"",
      person.ClientInternalPerson_ID,
      person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName,
      finalValue));
  }
}
```

You can use SelectMany to flatten this further, but that's a different question.  If you are expecting that there is 1 and only 1 record for each person where FinalValue!=null, then you can simplify it by using either `.First` or `.Single` like this:

```
foreach (Person person in persons)
{
  var finalValue = person.PersonDatas.First(x => x.FinalValue != null);

  sb.AppendLine(string.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\"",
    person.ClientInternalPerson_ID,
    person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName,
    finalValue));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below command returns an enumerable list pf PersonData objects that have non-null FinalValues:

```
var finalValue = person.PersonDatas.Where(x => x.FinalValue != null);
```

You would need to grab a specific PersonData object from the list. For example, the below would give you the FinalValue of the first PersonData object with a non-null FinalValue.

```
 var finalValue = person.PersonDatas.Where(x => x.FinalValue != null).First().FinalValue.ToString();
```

NOTE - The above code would throw an exception if there was no match. If you don't have a guarantee of that, you could do something like:

```
var finalValuePerson = person.PersonDatas.Where(x => x.FinalValue != null).FirstOrDefault();
var finalValue = (finalValuePerson != null) ? finalValuePerson.FinalValue : "";
```